# Hibernate annotations cascading doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, cascade

I've decided to change hbm.xml style to annotations using hibernate.
I had in my hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="by.sokol.jpr.data">
 <class name="Licence">
  <id name="licenceId">
   <generator class="native" />
  </id>
 <many-to-one name="user" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" column="usr"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And changed it to:

```
@Entity
public class Licence {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int licenceId;

 @ManyToOne(targetEntity=User.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
 private User user;
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity(name = "Usr")
public class User {

    // BEGIN user info
    @Basic
    private String uid;
    @Basic
    private String name;
    @Basic
    private String company;
    @Basic
    private String street;

    // user's zip code
    @Basic
    private String ubication;
    @Basic
    private String city;
    @Basic
    private String po;

    @Column(name = "useremail")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "assignedGen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "assignedGen", strategy = "assigned")
    private String email;
    @Basic
    private String challengPassword;
    @Basic
    private String serialNumber;
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
...
<mapping class="by.sokol.jpr.data.Licence" />
<mapping class="by.sokol.jpr.data.User" />
...
```

Java code to get session

```
...
AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
cfg.configure(new File(PROPERTIES_FILENAME));
sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
...
```

Java code for saving Licence object

```
org.hibernate.Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(licence);
t.commit();
```

generated sql:

```
Hibernate: select this_.licenceId as licenceId0_2_, this_.creationDate as creation2_0_2_, this_.limitDate as limitDate0_2_, this_.user_useremail as user4_0_2_, this_.workstation_motherboardId as workstat5_0_2_, user1_.useremail as useremail1_0_, user1_.challengPassword as challeng2_1_0_, user1_.city as city1_0_, user1_.company as company1_0_, user1_.name as name1_0_, user1_.po as po1_0_, user1_.serialNumber as serialNu7_1_0_, user1_.street as street1_0_, user1_.ubication as ubication1_0_, user1_.uid as uid1_0_, workstatio4_.motherboardId as motherbo1_2_1_, workstatio4_.computerName as computer2_2_1_, workstatio4_.macAddress as macAddress2_1_, workstatio4_.osId as osId2_1_ from Licence this_ inner join Usr user1_ on this_.user_useremail=user1_.useremail left outer join Workstation workstatio4_ on this_.workstation_motherboardId=workstatio4_.motherboardId where user1_.useremail=?
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into Licence (creationDate, limitDate, user_useremail, workstation_motherboardId, licenceId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

APPEND_1: working code

```
org.hibernate.Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(licence.getUser());
session.save(licence);
t.commit();
```

And hibernate doesn't save user on saving. I really need help!

Comment: I just want to point out that it should be spelled "License"

Comment: How are you saving the entity?  What sql is generated?

Comment: @Kevin: "Licence" is the normal UK spelling. For example: http://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/ The American version is creeping in, just as so many other American spellings, but the UK version is perfectly correct.

Comment: @T.J. I had no idea. Thanks for the info!

Comment: please answer the questions of Rpond

Comment: Added sql requests data and java code for saving object

Comment: everything seems ok. make sure you have the user != null at the moment of saving.

Comment: Yes its not null. I have attached code that works fine, but I dislike the way it goes (see APPEND_1 in my question post).

Comment: post the cascades in the way they look after taking the advice from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest getting rid of the `@Cascade` annotation, unless you need `delete-orphan`.

use only `cascade =  {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}`

Another thing to observe is whether you are using `AnnotationConfiguration`. If not, your annotations aren't parsed at all.

**Update:** Are you sure your user have the `email` field set? I'd suggest having an auto-generated id for the primary key of `User`. The `email` is the business key, on which `hashCode()` and `equals()` should be implemented.

Comment: Its my first experience on stackoverflow and I like it for quick answers. Here is what I can add according to replies:
1) cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST} - I tried it with no success

Comment: add these to your question, rather than as comments

Comment: Sorry I its my first experience. I've added information to my question

Answer (score 0):

Is your user defined as an entity? Not sure if it works with hbm and annotations mixed.
Is the relation bidirectional? Maybe you can show user class?